# How to declare the correct Express Err Type

Tags: typescript, express

Im defining the `err` as `any` because I dont know how to define it correctly. I expected to find an `express.Error` type but there wasn't one.

How should i set the type for `err`?

```
// Catch Syntax Error in JSON
app.use((err: any, req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
  if (err.status === 400 && err instanceof SyntaxError && 'body' in err) {
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'JSON Syntax Error' });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `err` is regarded as `any` according to the official type definition here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/6b3f9450aa2ced2bae7851acebc5ed9d7e6200c2/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L45

So I think it's ok to use `any` here.

Comment: I wish my linter agreed with you! Do you think this an ok way to solve it? `interface Error {status?: number;}` and then use `app.use((err: Error,...`